# Error calculating the mean due to a list which doesn't exist

Tags: python, pandas, numpy

I am attempting to calculate the average hourly fraction from a column of integers called `hour` in a pandas DataFrame df called `train`.

The code used to calculate is as follows:

`hourly_frac = train.groupby(['hour']).mean()/np.sum(train.groupby(['hour'].mean()))`

Which is following the FB Prophet tutorial https://www.analyticsvidhya.com/blog/2018/05/generate-accurate-forecasts-facebook-prophet-python-r/

However when trying to run this code I receive the following error:

`AttributeError: 'list' object has no attribute 'mean'`

This is confusing as the `dtype` of the object is `int64` and when checking the type it suggests it is a pandas series. Sample of the data is as follows:

`train.hour
Out[14]:

1          0 
2          0 
3          23
4          24
5          35
6          36`

I don't understand where the list is and why it would not be able to calculate the mean here. Any ideas as to what the error means?

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1):

It looks like you misplaced a parenthesis. Near the end of your line, the snippet:

```
['hour'].mean()
```

is trying to take the `mean` of `['hour']`, a `list` with a single element of type `str`. And so, as is proper, you're getting an `AttributeError`.

Just imagine if this line failed silently instead of raising an informative error: the kind of garbage you'd see in your final results would be downright fascinating.